# Excel match string 2 values verify on a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to verify if a name like C1"`hans`" c2 "`mueller`" is present on a Range also with "`firstname`" "`lastname`" in each field.

I tried this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(sheet2!$D:$E;D2:E2);"Yes";"No")
```

But this just works for one field like

```
=IF(COUNTIF(sheet2!$D:$E;D2:D2);"Yes";"No")
```

Please help me to get the two values verified if it is present on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is COUNTIFS (2007+):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(sheet2!$D:$D;D2;sheet2!$E:$E;E2)>0;"Yes";"No")
```

Backwards compatible would be SUMPRODUCT, but you don't want to use whole columns with sumproduct, so adjust ranges to suit:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(sheet2!$D$1:$D$100=D2);--(sheet2!$E$1:$E$100=E2))>0;"Yes";"No")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting the criteria paramater of the `COUNTIF` function incorrect?  I believe you are trying to see if values in C1, C2, etc. occur in columns D and E?

If so, then you'd want to change your formula to:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D:$E,C1),"Yes","No")
```

Which would tell you if the value in C1 occurs in either column D or E.